# How to get only 5 product in ASC order from cart in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
foreach ($this->cart->contents() as $key) {

    $total = $total + $key['price'];
    $subtotal = $subtotal + $key['price'];
    $clg_id = $key['clg_id'];
    $cityinfo = $this->site_model->selectcity_state($clg_id, "college_id", "tbl_college_details");
    $clg_premium = $this->site_model->select_premium($clg_id);
    $premium = $clg_premium[0];

    // What I would want to be able to do:
    if ($premium->premium == 'Y' && $count == '5') {
        $total = '499';
    } elseif($premium->premium == 'Y' && $count > '5') {

    }

}
```

i have 6 product in my cart what i want to do when user click to payement for the first 5 product payment in ASC order by price will count 499 and for rest one suppose it has 400 price will add with 499so for the 6 product price will be 899

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please elaborate.

Comment: i have 6 product in cart but for five product i am discount that first five product with less price will be paid by 499 and other product with highr price money will be add with 499 @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: ok @sunny Saini, we can help you if you print structure of the array with which you are using `foreach` loop. Because until we can see the values, how we can give you solution?

Comment: array(6) {
  ["ab213b9f30de0fe5e839cb6d58bf8e66"]=>
  array(11) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["qty"]=>
    float(1)
    ["price"]=>float(1)
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "MBA"
    ["clg_id"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["clg_name"]=>
    string(30) "Doon Business School, Dehradun"
    ["registration_fees"]=>string(4) "1000"
    ["premium"]=>string(1) "Y"
    ["options"]=>array(2) {
      ["image"]=>string(24) "1446200343phpVmqQur.jpeg"
      ["c_id"]=>string(2) "20"
    }
    ["rowid"]=>string(32) "ab213b9f30de0fe5e839cb6d58bf8e66"
    ["subtotal"]=>float(1)
  }}